# Can't set .data() for an element

Tags: jquery, element

I'm not able to add data to a dynamically added element:

```
var newItem = "<li>" + poi.Title + "</li>";
$(newItem).data('poiID', poi.ID);
$(newItem).data('poiTitle', poi.Title);
```

I've tried to add this:

```
alert($(newItem).data('poiID'));
```

right after the above line, but I keep getting "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like so:

```
var newItem = $("<li>" + poi.Title + "</li>");
newItem.data('poiID', poi.ID);
newItem.data('poiTitle', poi.Title);

...

alert(newItem.data('poiID'));
```

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/P4HWb/

Answer (score 1):

That's because everytime you do `$(newItem)` you're creating a new element and you're not actually storing a reference to it.

Try:

```
var newItem = $("<li>" + poi.Title + "</li>");  /* create element as newItem */
newItem.data('poiID', poi.ID);                  /* add data to existing elem */
alert(newItem.data('poiID'));                   /* peek at your data */
```

Do note that at this point your new element is not yet attached to your DOM. To have it appear on the page, you'll need attach `newItem` using methods such as `append()`, `prepend()`, etc.

Comment: tnx for the quick replay.. iv tried giving each new element an id.. but it didn't work :(

Comment: You can only search for them by id once they've been added to the DOM. However, if it's just the one element you're creating it's a lot simpler to just store a reference to it as shown in the example above.

Answer (score -1):

Your `newItem` is not in the DOM yet. Append it and then you can add `.data()` to it.

Or you can do something like this.

```
var newItem = $("<li>" + poi.Title + "</li>");
$(newItem).data('poi', poi); //That way the whole object is added to the element.
```

Then append it to the DOM.

Comment: i have tried the following :

                                var newItem = "<li>" + poi.Title + "</li>";
                                $("#itemsListPage>ul").append(newItem);
                                $(newItem).data('poiID', '123');
                                alert($(newItem).data('poiID'));  

but it didnt work :(

Comment: and tnx for the quick replay :)

Comment: Vote down huh? Interesting. Same answer as everyone else. You need to add it to the DOM and since `newItem` is a string, you have to re-declare it to the element that was appended.

var newItem = "<li>" + poi.Title + "</li>"; $("#itemsListPage>ul").append(newItem);
**var newItem = $("#itemsListPage>ul").find("li[title=" + poi.Title + "]");**
$(newItem).data('poiID', '123');
alert($(newItem).data('poiID'));

Comment: the vote down is not from me brother .. i still cant vote yet :) 
it seems someone is following u ;) hhh
tnx very much for the answer ^_^
and i awe u a vote up next time !

Comment: Thanks! The comment was just made in general. I usually do not downvote that early. I did make an edit, so maybe it was before the edit was seen. Oh well. I'll have to be quicker next time!

Comment: You are saying the reason data was not working is because it is not in the DOM, which is not true. The reason his code is not working is because he is creating new elements every time.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino I see your point. Thanks for pointing it out.